# Jailbroken iPhone stuck on Apple Logo after installing tweak

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

Im having  trouble with the restarting  process  when a tweak doesn't work on my jailbroken iPhone 6s. So when I installed a tweak that made my phone stay stuck on the apple logo. So I did the whole start-home then hold the  volume up button to get back to my home screen ok. Now my phone is in safe mode for Cydia and the only way to get my tweaks back after I take out the bad tweak is by restarting my phone by just holding down the power bottom. Now when I do this my phone gets stuck again on the apple logo. Can soon one help me please

Answer (score 3):

Usually, there are at least 5 ways to [fix an iPhone stuck on Apple screen](http://fixipadiphonestuckonapplelogo.aolor.com/) after jailbreak:

1. Force restart the iPhone;
2. [Use the Volume Up, Home and Power buttons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUq5cn05D7I);
3. Update or restore iPhone in recovery mode;
4. Restore iPhone in DFU mode;
5. Use a third-party tool.

Answer (score 0):

Factory reset, restore, re-jail break (if you must), don't download the offending tweak again